# How does start.exe work?

Tags: windows, powershell

I found out that start.exe might be useful as a tool intended to run installed programs. So I can run Word:

```
start winword # located in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\WINWORD.EXE"
```

Visual Studio:

```
start devenv # located in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

Skype

```
start skype # located in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\"
```

Waterfox

```
start waterfox #located in "C:\Program Files\Waterfox\waterfox.exe"
```

and even Notepad++

```
start notepad++ # located in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
```

But it does not work for steam,

```
PS C:\Users\Павел> start steam
start : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ start steam
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

however :

```
>Test-Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe'
True
```

my $PATH:

```
/usr/local/bin:/mingw/bin:/bin:/c/Program Files/Far Manager:/c/Program Files/Far Manager/ConEmu:/c/Program Files (x86)/ActiveState Komodo Edit 9/:/c/Python34/:/c/Python34/Scripts:/c/Perl64/site/bin:/c/Perl64/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/ActiveState Komodo Edit 8/:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn/:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/120/Tools/Binn/:/c/Program Files (x86)/CMake/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Windows Performance Toolkit/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/TypeScript/1.0/:/c/Program Files/SlikSvn/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone/:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/:/c/Ruby21/bin
```

(I used Git Bash to show it because PowerShell seems to shorten this long variable when I run gci)
How can I run Steam that way?

EDIT: It also does not work for VLC in the default installation

Comment: Let me guess, you used Chocolatey to install all of those programs except Steam?  Chocolately is adding them to path, `start` is not doing anything special.

Comment: Even though I can run `skype` without `start`, I can't run `notepad++`, `devenv`,  `winword` and `waterfox`. It definitely does something special

Comment: My guess is that the `++` in `notepad++` is not being parsed correctly by the shell, but when its passed as an arguement to `start` there's no problem.

Comment: What about other commands? 
Look
`$ winword
sh.exe": winword: command not found` but `start winword` does work

Comment: In powershell its behaviour is the same

Comment: FYI, the `start` command you're using in Powershell is not "start.exe," it's the `Start-Process` cmdlet.  You can see that by running `start -?`.

Comment: I know it. What I am trying to say is that their behaviour is the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your registry `App Paths` subkeys. It's located in HKCU and HKLM under `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`. Dont forget about 32bit and 64bit keys in HKLM.

The idea is that some application's installers create these keys, but others don't.